# How to hide() first element in a <asp:repeater>

Tags: c#, .net, datarepeater

This is my code :

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rpUbicazione">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="Field" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
            // elements
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and I'd like to hide first element. So I tried changing first line with :

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rpUbicazione" Visible="<%# (Container.ItemIndex != 0) %>">
```

but seems it doesnt works : `ItemIndex` it is not a method.

How can I do it?

Comment: Can you simply skip 1 on your datasource? ie., `repeater.DataSource = someList.Skip(1)`;

Comment: can you not remove the item from the `DataSource` before binding it to the `Repeater`?

Comment: Here is a link on StackOverFlow that appears to be the same issue in question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006867/hide-an-element-in-asp-net-based-on-an-if-inside-a-repeater

Comment: When you say you want to hide the first element, do you mean the Repeater itself? Because, you attempt at hiding is trying to hide the repeater itself.

Comment: I mean "display:none" to the first element :)

Comment: Anthony Pegram provided a great answer for this particular case. Should be an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rpUbicazione">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="Field" style='margin-bottom: 20px; display: <%# Container.ItemIndex == 0 ? "none" : "block"  %>'>
            // elements
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

or you can do something like this:

```
<script runat="server">
    protected void rpUbicazione_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemIndex == 0)
        {
            e.Item.FindControl("divElement").Visible = false;
        }
    }
</script>

<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rpUbicazione" onitemdatabound="rpUbicazione_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div id="divElement" runat="server" class="Field" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
            // elements
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```